# How to split a string with a space and leave anything inside a quotation alone?

Tags: java, regex, string

Given a string entered by a user, I'm trying to split the string by removing any whitespace and getting each token.

But I'm having difficulties for when I have a token in quotation marks. Here are some examples to better clarify:

User input: `that         is      cool`

Expected Output:

```
that
is
cool
```

User input: `The       book   "Harry Potter"   is   cool`

Expected Output:

```
The
book
"Harry Potter"
is
cool
```

User input: `Here  "     is   one   final   "    example`

Expected Output:

```
Here
"     is   one   final   "
example
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("User input: ");
    input = in.nextLine();
    input = input.trim();
    input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    String[] a = input.split(" ");

    for (String c: a) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

It only works for the first example but for the examples with quotations, it splits the spaces inside the quoted tokens swell. Example 3 output:

```
Here
"
is
one
final
"
example
```

Comment: Quotation flag, you should check every char against quotation and if you met such you should set this flag on and keep looking for close quotation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't focus on things you want to `split` on. It is easier to focus on things you want to `find` as result:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]+\"|\\S+");
//                                     quotes---  ^^^^^^^^^^ 
//                                     non+whitespace        ^^^^ 
public static List<String> splitTokensAndQuotes(String text) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        result.add(m.group());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Demo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    splitTokensAndQuotes("that         is      cool")
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("------");

    splitTokensAndQuotes("the       book   \"Harry Potter\"   is   cool")
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("------");

    splitTokensAndQuotes("Here  \"     is   one   final   \"    example")
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("------");

}
```

Result:

```
that
is
cool
------
the
book
"Harry Potter"
is
cool
------
Here
"     is   one   final   "
example
------
```

Comment: Very nice solution. I was actually thinking of finding the right regex myself, but couldn´t figure it out. My only criticism is that you´re making it java 8 specific without a good reason.

Comment: @wvdz Thanks :). Anyway it is over an year since Java 8 was introduced. Honestly I don't see any reason why not to use it in answer since `forEach` can be easily rewritten using for loop if someone can't use Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with that :

```
String str = "Here  \"     is   one   final   \"    example";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(str);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"|'([^']+)'|\\S+");
```

to match words between spaces or between quotes and spaces between them. It will also behave correctly with single quotes. It will keep `"it's"` as a single word that you may or may not want.

you would then iterate through all the matches like this

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitOnSpacesButNotOnStrings(
         "The       book   \"Harry Potter\"   is   cool"
    )));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitOnSpacesButNotOnStrings(
         "Here  \"     is   one   final   \"    example"
    )));
    // Output:
    // [The, book, "Harry Potter", is, cool]
    // [Here, "     is   one   final   ", example]
}

private static String[] splitOnSpacesButNotOnStrings(String s) {
    return s.split(" +(?=(?:(?:.*?\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
}
```

It will only work, though, if your strings are balanced, that is, contain an even number of `"`s.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I could think of was to write a little parser that simply traverses your input string and keeps a flag that tells you if you have an open quote or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "Here  \"     is   one   final   \"    example";
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean inQuote = false;

    input = input.trim();
    String token = "";
    for (char c : input.toCharArray())
    {
        if (c == ' ' && !inQuote)
        {
            if (token.length() > 0)
                tokens.add(token);
            token = "";
        }
        else
        {
            token += c;
            if (c == '"')
            {
                inQuote = !inQuote;
                if (!inQuote)
                {
                    tokens.add(token);
                    token = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (token.length() > 0)
        tokens.add(token);
    System.out.println(tokens);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What about this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringTokenizer stk;
    //String s="that         is      cool";
    //String s="The       book   "Harry Potter"   is   cool";
    String s = "Here  \"     is   one   final   \"    example";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
    scanner.useDelimiter(" +(?=(?:(?:.*?\\\"){2})*[^\\\"]*$)");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.next());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in one line:

```
String[] terms = input.trim().split(" +(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
```

This works by splitting on space(s) only when not within quotes, where "when not within quotes" is defined as "followed by an *even* number of quotes".

The call to `trim()` is optional given your examples, but would cater for leading the user entering leading spaces.

---

Some test code:

```
String input = "Here  \"     is   one   final   \"    example";
String[] terms = input.trim().split(" +(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
Arrays.stream(terms).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
Here
"     is   one   final   "
example
```